# while loop, try except and other functions having issues

Tags: python, list, if-statement, while-loop, try-except

I am creating a bingo/housie ticket creator in python. The tickets have 9 rows and 3 columns. It means 27 spaces on a 9*3 grid. 9 rows vertically and 3 columns horizontally. Each row can only hold 3 random numbers. The first row can hold a random number from 1,9. The second row can hold a random number from 10,19. The third row can hold a random number from 20,29. The fourth row can hold a random number from 30,39. The fifth row can hold a random number from 40,49. The sixth row can hold a random number from 50,59. The seventh row can hold a random number from 60,69.  The eighth row can hold a random number from 70,79. The ninth row can hold a random number from 80,90. Here is a reference image of the ticket. [image: Here is a reference image]
I am planning to create a random ticket in python. Here is the script I created for it. It has all the comments for better understanding.

```
import random

# print("Script is ready") 

# Variables
global numOfNums # This tells that only 15 numbers can be added to the ticket
numOfNums = 15
global allNum # this is the list containing all 90 numbers
global numToBedone # this is just for adding nums to the list
allNum = []
numToBedone = 1
global row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9 # all the rows
row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9 = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [] 
global row1Num, row2Num, row3Num, row4Num, row5Num, row6Num, row7Num, row8Num, row9Num # all the nums row can have 

# Filling the List
while numToBedone<91:  
    allNum.append(numToBedone)
    numToBedone = numToBedone+1 

# Generating number for row 1
def ranRow1NumGen():
    global numOfNums
    row1Num = random.randint(1,9)
    try:
        allNum.remove(row1Num)
    except:
        ranRow1NumGen()
    row1.append(row1Num)
    numOfNums = numOfNums - 1

# Generating number for row 2
def ranRow2NumGen():
    global numOfNums
    row2Num = random.randint(10,19)
    try:
        allNum.remove(row2Num)
    except:
        ranRow2NumGen()
    row2.append(row2Num)
    numOfNums = numOfNums - 1

# Generating number for row 3
def ranRow3NumGen():
    global numOfNums
    row3Num = random.randint(20,29)
    try:
        allNum.remove(row3Num)
    except:
        ranRow3NumGen()
    row3.append(row3Num)
    numOfNums = numOfNums - 1

# Generating number for row 4
def ranRow4NumGen():
    global numOfNums
    row4Num = random.randint(30,39)
    try:
        allNum.remove(row4Num)
    except:
        ranRow4NumGen()
    row4.append(row4Num)
    numOfNums = numOfNums - 1

# Generating number for row 5
def ranRow5NumGen():
    global numOfNums
    row5Num = random.randint(40,49)
    try:
        allNum.remove(row5Num)
    except:
        ranRow5NumGen()
    row5.append(row5Num)
    numOfNums = numOfNums - 1

# Generating number for row 6
def ranRow6NumGen():
    global numOfNums
    row6Num = random.randint(50,59)
    try:
        allNum.remove(row6Num)
    except:
        ranRow6NumGen()
    row6.append(row6Num)
    numOfNums = numOfNums - 1

# Generating number for row 7
def ranRow7NumGen():
    global numOfNums
    row7Num = random.randint(60,69)
    try:
        allNum.remove(row7Num)
    except:
        ranRow7NumGen()
    row7.append(row7Num)
    numOfNums = numOfNums - 1

# Generating number for row 8
def ranRow8NumGen():
    global numOfNums
    row8Num = random.randint(70,79)
    try:
        allNum.remove(row8Num)
    except:
        ranRow8NumGen()
    row8.append(row8Num)
    numOfNums = numOfNums - 1

# Generating number for row 9
def ranRow9NumGen():
    global numOfNums
    row9Num = random.randint(80,90)
    try:
        allNum.remove(row9Num)
    except:
        ranRow9NumGen()
    row9.append(row9Num)
    numOfNums = numOfNums - 1

# Main function for creating a ticket
def ticketGen():

    global row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9
    global numOfNums
    
    #Adding 1 number to all the rows
    ranRow1NumGen()
    ranRow2NumGen()
    ranRow3NumGen()
    ranRow4NumGen()
    ranRow5NumGen()
    ranRow6NumGen()
    ranRow7NumGen()
    ranRow8NumGen()
    ranRow9NumGen()
    
    # After we put 1 number in each row we have to put the rest in the random rows
    # I cant understand how to do that
    # I used this way but it has some issues
    # sometimes a row can get more than 3 num which isnt possible in the ticket
    # also some numbers repeat but I cant understand how as I have a try except statement
    u = 0
    while u < 6:
        randomNumGiver = random.randint(1,9)
        if numOfNums > 0:
            if randomNumGiver == 1 and len(row1) < 3:
                ranRow1NumGen()
            elif randomNumGiver == 2 and len(row2) < 3:
                ranRow2NumGen()
            elif randomNumGiver == 3 and len(row3) < 3:
                ranRow3NumGen()
            elif randomNumGiver == 4 and len(row4) < 3:
                ranRow4NumGen()
            elif randomNumGiver == 5 and len(row5) < 3:
                ranRow5NumGen()
            elif randomNumGiver == 6 and len(row6) < 3:
                ranRow6NumGen()
            elif randomNumGiver == 7 and len(row7) < 3:
                ranRow7NumGen()
            elif randomNumGiver == 8 and len(row8) < 3:
                ranRow8NumGen()
            elif randomNumGiver == 9 and len(row9) < 3:
                ranRow9NumGen()
            else:
                pass
        u = u+1

    # printing all the rows and the remaining numbers in the list
    print(row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9)
    pass

ticketGen()
```

I have gotten some mixed output :
Incorrect output given by the code :

```
[8] [14] [21, 25, 21] [32] [42, 47, 42] [55] [60, 66, 60] [76] [82]
```

Correct way and the output given by the code :

```
[7, 2] [16, 14] [28] [34] [40] [59, 56, 52] [68, 61, 64] [77] [83]
```

As you can see it has a mixed output. The issue with the first output is the numbers can't be repeated and also a row can't have more than 3 numbers. I can't find how this bug is happening as I have set a try-except statement for the repetition and an if statement for having less than 3 numbers. If you can find any issue and know the way to resolve it please do so. It would mean a lot to me. Thank you.

Edit - The code has now been changed according to the first answer but I got these results. Also at one point it clearly had more than 3 numbers in a row and they were duplicate numbers. Can't figure out a way please HELP

Comment: You do not need to use `global numOfNum` etc... at the global scale (i.e you must use them inside functions)

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop, change this -

```
while u < 6:
        randomNumGiver = random.randint(1,9)
        if randomNumGiver == 1 and numOfNums > 0 and row1.__len__() < 3:
            ranRow1NumGen()
        elif randomNumGiver == 2 and numOfNums > 0 and row2.__len__() < 3:
            ranRow2NumGen() ..........
```

To -

```
while u < 6:
    randomNumGiver = random.randint(1,9)
    if numOfNums > 0:
        if randomNumGiver == 1 and len(row1) < 3:
            ranRow1NumGen()
        elif randomNumGiver == 2 and len(row2) < 3:
            ranRow2NumGen()
        elif randomNumGiver == 3 and len(row3) < 3:
            ranRow3NumGen()
        elif randomNumGiver == 4 and len(row4) < 3:
            ranRow4NumGen()
        elif randomNumGiver == 5 and len(row5) < 3:
            ranRow5NumGen()
        elif randomNumGiver == 6 and len(row6) < 3:
            ranRow6NumGen()
        elif randomNumGiver == 7 and len(row7) < 3:
            ranRow7NumGen()
        elif randomNumGiver == 8 and len(row8) < 3:
            ranRow8NumGen()
        elif randomNumGiver == 9 and len(row9) < 3:
            ranRow9NumGen()
        else:
            pass
    u = u+1
```

Make the line `numOfNums` common and then use `len()` instead because it is better practice not to use `.__len__()`

Result: (No repetition and more than 3 when I tried it many times for any wrong result)

```
Script is ready
2 is selected for row1
12 is selected for row2
22 is selected for row3
35 is selected for row4
48 is selected for row5
56 is selected for row6
64 is selected for row7
75 is selected for row8
90 is selected for row9
[2] [12] [22] [35] [48] [56] [64] [75] [90]
19 is selected for row2
60 is selected for row7
39 is selected for row4
55 is selected for row6
53 is selected for row6
56 is selected for row6
[2] [12, 19] [22] [35, 39] [48] [56, 55, 53] [64, 60] [75] [90]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]
```

Comment: Bro I also want it to be reused. As I want the player to have the ability to regenerate a ticket. I did reset all the global values as a function and called the function in the start and end of ticketgen function and I got the same issues again. Any solutions for regeneration of the ticket? Btw the code worked fantastic when I generated 1 ticket but I can't rerun the whole script as this will be a function need to be called on a button press so please help